# A rest that call another rest and response "400 bad request"

Tags: java, rest

I'm programming in Java a REST that calls another REST. The response from the second REST is transformed into a object and added into a List, and when the List has 12 elements, the REST response should be "400 bad request".

I'm receiving the error in the GET of this method. I have a `foreach` that calls this method 20 times. The first 11 times work, but the 12th time I receive the bad request.

Client call:

```
private String callAcountingDebitCreditServiceAcount(
            long originalOption, long codeInstance, long codeCompany, String codeBranch,
            String codeOffice, String currency, String inputCost, long operationNumber,
            String jsonResult, long originalOptionMenu, long codeTrans, String tableName,
            String pkJson)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        String jsonFuente = jsonResult;
        jsonFuente = URLEncoder.encode(jsonFuente, "utf-8");
        String pkj = URLEncoder.encode(pkJson, "utf-8");
        String URLrest = "http://llacsaa-server:9080/JorupeInstanceWS/webresources/accountingDebitCreditService";
        String respuestaStr = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target(URLrest)
            .queryParam("codeInstance", codeInstance)
            .queryParam("codeCompany", codeCompany)
            .queryParam("codeTrans", codeTrans)
            .queryParam("codeBrach", codeBranch)
            .queryParam("codeOffice", codeOffice)
            .queryParam("originalOption", originalOption)
            .queryParam("currency", currency)
            .queryParam("inputCost", inputCost)
            .queryParam("operationNumber", operationNumber)
            .queryParam("jsonArrayScreen", jsonFuente)
            .queryParam("originalOptionMenu", originalOptionMenu)
            .queryParam("tableName", tableName)
            .queryParam("pkJson", pkj)
            .request()
            .get(String.class);
        ResponseRest respuesta = new ResponseRest();
        return respuesta.process(respuestaStr).toString();
    }
```

Enpoint code:

```
@Stateless
@Path("accountingDebitCreditService")
public class AccountingDebitCreditREST {

@Inject
private ServiceRegistry services;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseRest accountingDebitCredit(
        @QueryParam("originalOption") long originalOption,
        @QueryParam("codeInstance") long codeInstance,
        @QueryParam("codeCompany") long codeCompany,
        @QueryParam("codeBrach") String codeBranch,
        @QueryParam("codeOffice") String codeOffice,
        @QueryParam("currency") String currency,
        @QueryParam("inputCost") String inputCost,
        @QueryParam("operationNumber") long operationNumber,
        @QueryParam("jsonArrayScreen") String jsonArrayScreen,
        @QueryParam("originalOptionMenu") long originalOptionMenu,
        @QueryParam("codeTrans") long codeTrans,
        @QueryParam("tableName") String tableName,
        @QueryParam("pkJson") String pkJson)
```

Comment: Please provide some more information. Which `REST API` are you calling? What does your request look like?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. You should edit your question and add some context and some code. Bad Request usually is a client error (malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, deceptive request routing, etc).

Comment: i have edited the question ty

Comment: It seems that you might be sending the parameters wrong (maybe you mispelled any of the params) or maybe you are missing the content-type or some header. Check or provide the endpoint inteface (accountingDebitCreditService).

Comment: that is accountingDebitCreditService definition that process all and response a ResponseRest

Comment: but the error isn't when i call the rest, i have receiving the error in the response, "accountingDebitCreditService" make his process but when the rest receive his response i catch that error

Comment: Yes, I understood. But it is good to show a little more information so we may help you with a little more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try replacing

```
.request()
```

By:

```
.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
```

And don't forget the import:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
```